# Statistical test if one sample is placed higher in rank

Tags: hypothesis-testing, ranking, ranks

I have a rank array, say from 0 to 100 (0 being the smallest and 100 being the largest). If my data contains 89, 91, 94, and 98, I can say my data is significantly high in the rank. In other words, my null distribution would be my data is distributed in a uniform fashion across the ranks.

How can I test this (to get a p-value)?

Comment: So you have four data points? Are they independent, i.e. could the second rank also have been 89, or mutually exclusive?

Comment: This is a toy example, but basically in a similar scale (doesn't have to be exactly four though). And they are independent in the sense of mutual exclusiveness.

Comment: No, if they are exclusive they are not independent, because a value already taken is no longer possible for another value.

Comment: Yes, they are sampled at the same time from a same population, not one by one with replacement, so they are exclusive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For each single data point, the $p$-value is the probability to obtain that rank or a higher one. Therefore for 89, the $p$-value would be the number of ranks that high or higher, which is 12, divided by the number of possible ranks overall, 101, with the result $p = \frac{12}{101}$. For your data, the $p$-values are 0.1188, 0.0990, 0.0693, and 0.0297.

If we ignore the issue of dependence, we can use a method of combining $p$-values. One classic approach to do that is [Fisher's method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%27s_method), according to which
$$
-2\sum_{i=1}^k \log(p_i)
$$
is $\chi^2$-distributed with $2k$ degrees of freedom. This method tests the null hypothesis that *all* the sampled ranks are uniformly distributed over the whole range. Applied to your data, this gives an overall $p$-value of 0.0064. Since we have only 4 values out of 101, the induced dependence is probably weak, and since the $p$-value is quite small, we can be confident about the significance of the result.

To account for the dependence, or rather remove it, we can instead consider the ranks in the set after having virtually removed all the other sampled values. E.g. 89 has still the rank 89, but among 98 values, 98 has the rank 95 among 98 values, etc. Using this method, we get the $p$-values 0.0918, 0.0816, 0.0612, 0.0306, and the combined $p$-value 0.0043. It appears that in this case, the dependence made the naive test above too conservative. We are well below the conventional threshold of 0.05, and even below the stricter threshold 0.01, so the answer is, yes, these values are significantly high-ranked.

---

Previous version:

> To account for the dependence, we can adjust the subsequent ranks by removing the previous data. E.g. the second number has rank 91 within the original 101 values, but rank 90 within 100 values after we remove 89, and so on. Using this method, we get the $p$-values 0.1188, 0.1089, 0.0891, 0.0594, and the combined $p$-value 0.0139. The drawback of this approach is that the result depends on the sequence in which the partial $p$-values are computed. Going in ascending order gives particularly large $p$-values, and going in descending order particularly small ones: 0.0297, 0.06, 0.0808, 0.0918, with a combined value of 0.0041. Either way, we are well below the conventional threshold of 0.05, so the answer is, yes, these values are significantly high-ranked.

---

Here's a Matlab implementation of the final method:

```
% number of ranks
N = 101;
% ranks go from 0 to N - 1

% sampled ranks
ranks = [89, 91, 94, 98];
n = numel(ranks);

% adjust ranks by virtually removing other sampled values
for i = 1 : n
    r(i) = ranks(i) - sum(ranks < ranks(i));
end
ranks = r;
N = N - n + 1;

% compute single p-values
ps = (N - ranks) / N;

% apply Fisher's method
cs = -2 * sum(log(ps));
df = 2 * n;
p = chi2cdf(cs, df, 'upper')
```

Comment: Great! I was thinking of one-sample Wilcoxon or something like that, but that I can't use the whole sample set for the test was bothering me. In your way, I don't need to worry which representative value I have to pick up!

Comment: @user1586400, glad you like it. Have you seen my edit, just now?

Comment: Again, thanks a lot. I just accepted your answer. But it seems my upvote doesn't count, because my reputation hasn't reached there yet. I just hope that by the time I get out of "nobody" status, the system remembers my choice and apply.

Answer (score 1):

A. Donda's answer seems interesting. It would fit well if there was a replacement process, but maybe - as he pointed out, for the reasons he put forward - a bit conservative.

I think that a more classical way to handle this would be to go for a Wilcoxon test. At least I don't see a specific reason why it would be not adapted for this case.

```
> selected=c(89,91,94,98)
> all=0:100
> notSelected=all[! all %in% selected ]
> wilcox.test(selected,notSelected,alternative="greater")

    Wilcoxon rank sum test with continuity correction

data:  selected and notSelected
W = 366, p-value = 0.001412
alternative hypothesis: true location shift is greater than 0
```

Comment: Thank you @brumar, I was thinking of this at first, but doesn't this assume normal distribution of the data points?

Comment: Not at all, it's non parametric. The test is **made to** compare ranks !

Comment: Oh I remember why I didn't use this. This test takes two samples, but in my case, I had one sample and one population. In your example, you took selected and notSelected as two independent samples, but selected is actually sampled from notSelected. What do you think, @brumar?

Comment: I don't think it's a problem. If I told you "let's build a score which tells how better are the ranks of your sample compared to the rest of the population" and "let's do a permutation test to see how often a random rearrangement of your sample ranks get a better score by chance" would you be more convinced ? (The Wilcoxon test works broadly like that). W is this score, and the p-value is how often it can be obtained by chance (random permutation).

Answer (score 0):

There are two good answers here.  I thought I might list a couple additional possibilities.

From your description, it sounds like you are interested in if your ranks are higher than average.  If so, that could be tested with a [sign test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sign_test), i.e., a binomial test of whether the proportion greater than some rank (say 50th) is $>.5$.  Here's a simple example using your data, coded in R:

```r
binom.test(x=4, n=4)
#   Exact binomial test
# 
# data:  4 and 4
# number of successes = 4, number of trials = 4, p-value = 0.125
# alternative hypothesis: true probability of success is not equal to 0.5
# 95 percent confidence interval:
#  0.3976354 1.0000000
# sample estimates:
# probability of success 
#                      1
```

On the other hand, if you really want to test if your *distribution* differs from the uniform distribution, you could use a distribution test, like the [Kolmogorov-Smirnov test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov%E2%80%93Smirnov_test).  (Note that not being uniform doesn't necessarily mean they're better.)

```r
ks.test(x=c(89, 91, 94, 98), "punif", min=0, max=100)
#   One-sample Kolmogorov-Smirnov test
# 
# data:  c(89, 91, 94, 98)
# D = 0.89, p-value = 0.0002928
# alternative hypothesis: two-sided
```